# SIGTRAP Crash with unhelpful stacktrace

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I am seeing users experience this crash however I cannot reproduce I cant gather any useful information from the stack trace, nor see how it is even possible for the code to crash.

```
Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x101761e98
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftFoundation.dylib             0x0000000101761e98 0x101734000 + 188056
1   Workyard                             0x00000001001a30c4 @objc (extension in Workyard):__ObjC.WBLJobRecipient.isBuyerLastActor.getter : Swift.Bool (WBLJobRecipient+Extensions.swift:42)
2   Workyard                             0x00000001001a3188 (extension in Workyard):__ObjC.WBLJobRecipient.lastActionTime.getter : Foundation.Date (WBLJobRecipient+Extensions.swift:46)
3   Workyard                             0x00000001001a3148 @objc (extension in Workyard):__ObjC.WBLJobRecipient.lastActionTime.getter : Foundation.Date (WBLJobRecipient+Extensions.swift:0)
4   Workyard                             0x0000000100260548 @objc (extension in Workyard):__ObjC.WBLJob.lastActionTimestamp.getter : Foundation.Date (WBLJob+Extensions.swift:16)
5   Foundation                           0x000000018952a524 _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors + 368
6   Foundation                           0x0000000189618e50 -[NSSet(NSKeyValueSorting) sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:] + 560
7   Workyard                             0x000000010008ef14 -[WBLJobSummaryViewController populateDataWithJobSummary:] (WBLJobSummaryViewController.m:105)
8   Workyard                             0x000000010008fb54 -[WBLJobSummaryViewController viewWillAppear:] (WBLJobSummaryViewController.m:261)
9   UIKit                                0x000000018e9e2754 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 620
10  UIKit                                0x000000018e9e24cc -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 152
```

where buyerLastActionTime & sellerLastActionTime are Dates defined below and lastAction is a date coming from the backend that may or may not be null

Declaration

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *buyerLastActionTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *sellerLastActionTime;
```

Assigning

```
recipient.sellerLastActionTime =  lastAction ? lastAction : [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
recipient.buyerLastActionTime =  lastAction ? lastAction : [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
```

snippet from class where crash is happening

```
var isBuyerLastActor: Bool {
:42    return buyerLastActionTime > sellerLastActionTime
}

var lastActionTime: Date {
:46    return (isBuyerLastActor ? buyerLastActionTime : sellerLastActionTime) ??  Date()
}
```

Comment: If `buyerLastActionTime` & `sellerLastActionTime` were non-Optional, compiler would report error for  `??  Date()` in `lastActionTime`. Show how you declare these two properties and assign values to them.

Comment: @OOPer I have added in the decleration

Comment: You have shown how you _assign values_, but not how you declare. Also, Swift cannot compile the two lines you added.

Comment: Ah yes sorry I have added the declaration now which (as well as the assignment) is in an objective C class @OOPer

Comment: With such declaration, the two properties are imported as `Date!` (aka `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Data>`), which **can be nil**. You may be accessing the property `lastActionTime` before the _Assigning_ two lines run. Check your app's control flow and find where `lastActionTime` is accessed.

Comment: The crash seems to be in the getter for a Bool however (if we are to believe the stack trace).